# C++ 2010 Express Protobuf Compiling Errors

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am having a lot of trouble compiling protobuf source code(2.4.1) for the .lib and .dlls.  I followed google's intructions in the readme, word-for-word, but gtest has major errors.  Although, I get the libprotobuf.lib, libprotobuf-lite.lib, and libprotoc.lib, does having gtest fail matter?  Also, I can compile libprotobuf into a .dll but for libprotobuf-lite.dll, and libprotoc.dll the build fails with errors.

My question:  How can I still use protobuf for programing in msvc++ 2010 express.  Is there anyone else that implements it?

Thanks.

EDIT:: some build errors ...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: libprotobuf, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: gtest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: libprotobuf-lite, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  gtest.cc
3>  zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc
1>  zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc
2>c:\users\null\desktop\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h(745): error C3855: 'std::tr1::tuple_element': template parameter '_Idx' is incompatible with the declaration
2>c:\users\null\desktop\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h(757): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'
2>          c:\users\null\desktop\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h(742) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'
2>c:\users\null\desktop\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h(757): error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'type'
2>c:\users\null\desktop\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h(757): error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\null\desktop\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h(761): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'
```

Comment: I would be worried by a major failures in gtest. If you want some help I would post the build errors you get otherwise any answers you get would be just guesses.

Comment: @jahhaj The error list is very very long.  Where can I upload it to?  -- tyczj no update yet ...

Comment: @Ohmages: If you post the first few errors that will likely be enough. Or you could try http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Well I can tell you what the problem is, if not the solution. One of the gtest headers is defining a class called std::tr1::tuple_element. MS define a different class with exactly the same name, you can find it in the <utility> header file. I don't see any way to fix this other than to wait for google to do so. It is a problem that has been reported to them https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/protobuf/wNVDiburA1Q[1-25]. Alternatively you could download the precompiled Windows version.

Comment: @jahhaj  Thank you!  If you could make an answer like your comment, and then be so kind to provide a link to download per-compiled libs/dlls I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can tell you what the problem is, if not the solution. One of the gtest headers is defining a class called `std::tr1::tuple_element`. MS define a different class with exactly the same name, you can find it in the <utility> header file. I don't see any way to fix this other than to wait for google to do so. It is a problem that has been [reported](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/protobuf/wNVDiburA1Q%5B1-25%5D) to them.

Alternatively you could download the [pre-compiled Windows version](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protoc-2.4.1-win32.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: Hey, I was wondering, the pre-compiled .zip windows version comes with protoc.exe, when ran (as admin) does not produce any .dlls or .libs.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ohmages Sorry, no idea, I've never used protobuf before.

Answer (score 2):

I had this too. Thanks to jahhaj for the pointer. I tried just changing `tuple_element` to `tuple__element` (double underscore) in gtest-tuple.h. It's used 3 times, one of which is in a comment.

Everything then compiled fine both in Debug and Release and all the tests ran successfully.

There were a few warnings that came up during the compilation but as far as I could tell they were either deliberate or vagaries of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've been using MSVC 2008 far too long just because of this this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem as well.  Since I was using `Visual Studio 2010`, `std::tr1::tuple` is actually defined.

Reading a bit in the README file, section **Choosing a TR1 Tuple Library**, lead me to trying the compiler flag `-DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=0` or in Visual Studio would simply be `GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=0`.

This solved my issue since this tuple is already defined in the TR1 features provided in Visual Studio 2010.